# Calculate fields in objects of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to know the number of fields in object.

Suppose the collection is test and object is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b710714773d477d6779a0ac"),
    "_class" : "com.test.finddevice",
    "deviceId" : {
        "_id" : "abc",
        "kind" : "abc"
    },
    "id" : 123,
    "date" : ISODate("2018-08-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "usage" : NumberLong(0),
    "Status" : "pass",
    "valid" : false,
    "name" : "xyx",
    "State" : "qwerty"
} .
```

Here total fields in object are 10. Is their a way I can find or query based on field size like less than 10 or greater than 10?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query in 3.6.

Use [`$objectToArrray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to convert all top key & value pair into document arrays followed by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) to get the array size.

You can use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to use aggregation functions in regular query. [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) expression to compare the array size with input value.

[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) for referencing the top level document.

```
db.col.find([
  {"$expr":{"$lt":[{"$size":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}}, 10]}}
])
```

Comment: did this answer work for you ?